# Calculate Percentage in mysql for each site

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure with `columns Site, Item Amount,Item Weight`. I want to calculate the percentage for each site. I have tried this query but getting wrong % value. Please help.

```
Site |  Item Amount |  Item Weight 
 A   |    1000      |    50
 B   |    800       |    35
 C   |    1500      |    65 

 Select Site, sum(Item Amount) As Amount, sum(Item Weight)
 AS MT,concat(round((Item Amount/sum(Item Amount)*100),2),%)
 AS percentage from 'table1' group by site.
```

Comment: Wait...do you want percentages for multiple columns?

Comment: show some data or table structure and required output.

Comment: You have columns with space in their name ? Protect them with **`** in your queryAnyway, you should use '%' and not %
And no need to use 'table1', table1 is fine.

Comment: Great. I see you added data. What output do you desire?

Comment: Unfortunately this sample data won't clear up very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a subquery to calculate the total sum, you can use a `CROSS JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT t1.Site, sum(t1.`Item Amount`) As Amount, sum(t1.`Item Weight`) AS MT,
    SUM(t1.`Item Amount`) / t2.itemSum * 100 AS `Item percentage`,
    SUM(t1.`Item Weight`) / t3.weightSum * 100 AS `Weight percentage`
FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN
(SELECT SUM(`Item Amount`) AS itemSum FROM table1) t2 CROSS JOIN
(SELECT SUM(`Item Weight`) AS weightSum FROM table1) t3
GROUP BY t1.Site
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need percent of each site as compared to the total in the database:

```
select
  site,
  sum(`Item Amount`) as TotalItemAmount,
  sum(`Item Amount`)*100/(select sum(`Item Amount`) from table1) as ItemAmountPercent,
  sum(`Item Weight`) as TotalItemWeight,
  sum(`Item Weight`)*100/(select sum(`Item Weight`) from table1) as ItemWeightPercent
from table1
group by site
```

This should do it for you, I believe. This query groups the sites. For each site, it totals up item amount and divides it by total of item amount in the entire table. Same goes with item weight.

Comment: Thanks. Your query helped.